# Enemy ship health - using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm here asking a question for my son who has just started out with Python. 
He's working on a simple game where and enemy ship drops missiles and the player moves a shield to block falling missiles from hitting earth. He's added the ability for the shield to fire bullets at the ship to destroy it (set to 3 hits at the moment) which all seems to work but the game crashes at that point with the error given: typeerror: Die() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given). 
He's pretty stuck as to why and I'm not much use passed a bit of HTML :)

Here's his code:

```
#Space Defence
#Wes L-M

#Players must defend the city from alien missiles and attack the mother ship 

from livewires import games, color
import random
import pygame

games.init(screen_width = 1280, screen_height = 1024, fps = 50)
pygame.display.set_mode((1280,1024),pygame.FULLSCREEN)


class Killer(games.Sprite):
    """ Makes a simple die methord for all the class's. """

    def die(self):
        """ Destroy self. """
        self.destroy()


class Collider(Killer):
    """ A class that detects collisions. """
    def update(self):
        """ Check for overlapping sprites. """
        super(Collider, self).update()

        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            for sprite in self.overlapping_sprites:
                sprite.die()
            self.die()

    def die(self):
        """ Destroy self and leave explosion behind. """
        new_explosion = Explosion(x = self.x, y = self.y)
        games.screen.add(new_explosion)
        self.destroy()


class Collider_B(Killer):
    """ A class that detects collisions for Bullet and Ship. """

    def update(self):
        """ Check for overlapping sprites and take way from health. """
        super(Collider_B, self).update()

        if self.overlapping_sprites:
            for sprite in self.overlapping_sprites:
                sprite.die()
            self.die()

    def die(self):
        """ destroy self and leave differant explostion behind. """
        new_explosion = Explosion(x = self.x, y = self.y)
        games.screen.add(new_explosion)
        self.destroy()


class  Explosion(games.Animation):
    """ Explosion animation. """
    images = ["explosion_1.bmp",
              "explosion_2.bmp",
              "explosion_3.bmp",
              "explosion_4.bmp",
              "explosion_5.bmp",
              "explosion_6.bmp",
              "explosion_7.bmp",
              "explosion_8.bmp",
              "explosion_9.bmp"]

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Explosion, self).__init__(images = Explosion.images,
                                        x = x, y = y,
                                        repeat_interval = 6, n_repeats = 1,
                                        is_collideable = False)


class Shield(Killer):
    """
    A Shield controlled by player to catch falling missiles.
    """
    image = games.load_image("shield.bmp")
    BULLET_DELAY = 20

    def __init__(self, y = 800):
        """ Initialize Shield object and create Text object for score. """
        super(Shield, self).__init__(image = Shield.image,
                                  x = games.screen.width/2,
                                  y = y)
        self.bullet_wait = 0

        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width - 10,
                                is_collideable = False)
        games.screen.add(self.score)

    def update(self):
        """ Use A and D to controll, SPACE too fire. """
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_o):
            self.x -= 12
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_p):
            self.x += 12

        if self.left < 0:
            self. left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width

        self.Check_catch()

        #fire bullets if spacebar is pressed
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_SPACE) and self.bullet_wait == 0:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self.x, self.y)
            games.screen.add(new_bullet)
            self.bullet_wait = Shield.BULLET_DELAY

        #if waiting until the shield can fire next, decrease wait
        if self.bullet_wait > 0:
            self.bullet_wait -= 1

    def Check_catch(self):
        """ Check if catch missiles. """
        for missile in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score.value += 10
            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10
            missile.handle_caught()


class Ship(Killer):
    """
    A ship which moves left and right, dropping shield.
    """
    image = games.load_image("ship.bmp")
    health = 3

    def __init__(self, y = 55, speed = 3, odds_change = 200):
        """ Initialize the Chef object. """
        super(Ship, self).__init__(image = Ship.image,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = y,
                                   dx = speed)

        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0

    def update(self):
        """ Determine if direction needs to be reversed. """
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx

        self.check_drop()
        self.check_hit()


    def check_drop(self):
        """ Decrease countdown or drop missile reset countdown. """
        if self.time_til_drop > 0:
            self.time_til_drop -= 1
        else:
            new_missile = Missile(x = self.x)
            games.screen.add(new_missile)

            #set buffer to approx 30% of missile height, regardless of missile speed
            self.time_til_drop = int(new_missile.height * 1.3 / Missile.speed) + 1

    def check_hit(self):
        """ Check if Bullet has hit. """
        for Bullet in self.overlapping_sprites:
            Bullet.handle_hit()


class Bullet(Collider_B):
    """ A Bullet fired by the player's shield. """
    image = games.load_image("bullet.bmp")
    BUFFER = -30
    LIFETIME = 100

    def __init__(self, shield_x, shield_y):
        """ Initialize bullet sprite. """

        #bullet starting position
        buffer_y = Bullet.BUFFER
        x = shield_x 
        y = shield_y + buffer_y

        #bullet speed
        dx = random.choice([1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0, -0.1, -0.3, -0.5, -1])
        dy = -10

        #create the bullet
        super(Bullet, self).__init__(image = Bullet.image,
                                     x = x, y = y,
                                     dx = dx, dy = dy)
        self.lifetime = Bullet.LIFETIME

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """

        #if lifetime is up, destroy missile
        self.lifetime -= 1
        if self.lifetime == 0:
            self.destroy()

    def handle_hit(self):
        """ Handles what happens when hit by Bullet. """
        Ship.health -= 1
        if Ship.health == 0:    #ship loses health and eventually dies
            Ship.die()

        self.die()


class Missile(Collider):
    """
    A missile which falls to the ground.
    """
    image = games.load_image("missile.bmp")
    speed = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y = 90):
        """ Initialize a Missile object. """
        super(Missile, self).__init__(image = Missile.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,  
                                    dy = random.randint(1, 4))  
    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.end_game()
            self.die()

    def handle_caught(self):
        """ Destroy self if caught. """
        self.die()

    def handle_hit(self):
        """ Handle if missile gets hit... nothing. """

    def end_game(self):
        """ End the games. """
        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
                                    size = 90,
                                    color = color.red,
                                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                                    y = games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime = 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)


def main():
    """ Play the game. """
    city_image = games.load_image("Citybackground.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = city_image

    #load and play theme music
    games.music.load("Star-Command.mp3")
    games.music.play(-1)

    the_ship = Ship()
    games.screen.add(the_ship)

    the_shield = Shield()
    games.screen.add(the_shield)

    games.mouse.is_visible = False

    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

#start it up!!!!
main()
```

Comment: The error occurs in a function named `Die` but you only show code for `die` so we can't help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your reply... This is all his code. Is there a Function missing? The TypeError names die()  (not Die) my typo......

Comment: That's why you should always copy and paste.  You're wasting the time of everyone looking at this post because its not formatted properly and you retyped the error.

Comment: +1 for formatting.  Now please include the complete error with the stack traceback instead of just the last line.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know how to copy from command prompt...

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence>Space_Defence.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence\Space_Defence.py", line 274, in <mod
ule>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence\Space_Defence.py", line 271, in main

    games.screen.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 308, in mainloop

Comment: object._tick()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 506, in _tick
    self.update()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence\Space_Defence.py", line 155, in upda
te
    self.check_hit()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence\Space_Defence.py", line 172, in chec
k_hit
    Bullet.handle_hit()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence\Space_Defence.py", line 211, in hand
le_hit
    Ship.die()
TypeError: die() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\space_defence>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: put error message in question, not in comment.

Comment: you use `Ship.die()` but `die`  can be use only with instance `the_ship.die()`

Comment: Jesus, The reason I'm asking for help on behalf of my son is that he was scared of being knocked back by pedantic responders. You're not helping with my efforts to persuade him to seek help using forums. How do I edit the original question to include the complete traceback?

Comment: as for me `handle_hit` should be part of `Ship`, not `Bullet`

Comment: @jckm2000 Click here: [edit] Also see my answer

Comment: @jckm2000 You should read the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Here:

```
def handle_hit(self):
        """ Handles what happens when hit by Bullet. """
        Ship.health -= 1
        if Ship.health == 0:    #ship loses health and eventually dies
            Ship.die()

        self.die()
```

Here, you are trying to call an instance method on the class. (kind of like trying to repair the plumbing on a blueprint of the house) `Ship` capital refers to the blueprint of the ship, python is simply telling you that it doesn't know which ship to kill (even if there is only one ship).

Try replacing it with this:

```
def handle_hit(self):
        """ Handles what happens when hit by Bullet. """
        the_ship.health -= 1
        if the_ship.health == 0:    #ship loses health and eventually dies
            the_ship.die()

        self.die()
```

Also in `main()` add:

```
global the_ship
```

at the top of the function

Comment: it can be one problem - `the_ship` is local variable in `main()` ;)

Comment: @furas This isn't java, so we can access variables outside of scope. Ah, python. :)

Comment: This will require a `global the_ship` in `main()`. OP may not know it. :)

Comment: @jckm2000 Please accept the answer if you think it was useful. (Checkmark below the up and down symbols)

Comment: @jckm2000 It gives me reputation on the site if you accept the answer, which is like a reward because you can use it to set bounties and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

this code is fundamentally wrong. Besides the fact that the module "color" doesn't exist within livewires (it's "colour"). According to the code OP tries to init the games library with a width, height and fps. A quick search for the source code shows that the correct call would be:

```
    screen = games.Screen(width=1280, height=1024)
```

This means that the code in the main function is wrong as it keeps calling on functions which don't exist. Furthermore I haven't the faintest clue where the OP found the music module since a second quick search on github shows that in the livewires library no reference of "music" appears. The pygame module, however, contains a music player but isn't called remotely in the same way as OP implies. I have no idea how OP ever got this code to run.

If for some weird reason the code runs for OP:

```
def handle_hit(self):
    """ Handles what happens when hit by Bullet. """
    Ship.health -= 1
    if Ship.health == 0:    #ship loses health and eventually dies
        Ship.die()

    self.die()
```

Is also wrong, since in this code he references the class Ship instead of the instance he created. The best solution I can give OP in this case, is to chance all occurences of Ship inside the handle_hit() method to the "the_ship" instance variable

Comment: Don't post an answer if you're not answering

Comment: @DamianChrzanowski I've answered his question in the last paragraph. The first two paragraphs were actually critique on the code and offers some improvement to make the code run.

Comment: Fair enough, but it still is more of a speculation. Anyway I won't argue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10591043)

Comment: @AlexJolig See my comment directed to DamianChrzanowski

Comment: My son tells me that the Livewires he's using came as part of the book Python Programming For Beginners 3rd Edition that he's been working through. I think the author edited Livewires to use the US spelling of colour and added a music module. I'll pass on what you say about screen size etc. "the_ship" worked out, Thanks :)